# Resolvconf -u gives the error "resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf must be a symlink"

Tags: networking, resolv.conf

I use resolvconf to have static DNS servers set in `/etc/resolv.conf`. However, when I run `sudo resolvconf -u` to update `/etc/resolv.conf` with new static information, I get the error 'resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf must be a symlink'. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's easy to fix. Just open a terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: This information is obsolete. /etc/resolv.conf must now be symlinked to ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf.

Comment: The claim that the error message is caused by an interrupted resolvconf run is false.

Comment: Now it's right. :)

Comment: @jdthood : why is `../` needed? Why shouldn't we use `sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @Basj The difference is that it makes the symlink relative: read it as something like "go up a folder, then to 'run', then to 'resolvconf', then to the file 'resolv.conf'". I'm guessing either way works, but why hardcode a path? What if you are working with LXC containers (where the root FS is in a folder)? Then opening the link from the LXC host will take you to the wrong file if you used an absolute path.

Comment: @Azendale Could you please put the above comment in your answer, or do you mind if I edit the answer to include this information? I was about to ask this very question about the relative paths from a similar (separate) answer on another SE site. It's useful info. Cheers!

Comment: `grep: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory`

Comment: In case you wouldn't be able to remove `resolve.conf`. you should try `sudo chattr -a -i /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 15):

As of Ubuntu 12.04 resolvconf is part of the base system.  You can recreate the needed symlink by running

```
dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

or by doing the following in a terminal.

```
sudo ln -nsf ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Note that as of Ubuntu 12.10 resolvconf no longer aborts if /etc/resolv.conf is not a symlink.  It does print a warning message, but this can be silenced by putting the line

```
REPORT_ABSENT_SYMLINK=no
```

in /etc/default/resolvconf.

Comment: I'm assuming doing the `dpkg-reconfigure` command changes `/etc/resolv.conf` back to being a symlink, even if a normal file is at `/etc/resolv.conf`? Also, do you have to remove `/etc/resolv.conf` before doing `ln`? I get an error trying it on my system, but then again, I wasn't having the error described in this question when I tried it.

Comment: Yes, running "dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf" changes /etc/resolv.conf back into a symlink and if there was a file there; it saves a copy of the original file at /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original. It's a good idea to remove /etc/resolv.conf before putting a symlink there, but if you use "ln -nsf" it's not necessary to do so. I have just changed the answer to say "ln -nsf" instead of "ln -s".

Answer (score 1):

rm -r resolv.conf
nano resolv.conf
in it do

nameserver 1.1.1.1

nameserver 1.0.0.1

save it with ctrl+ X.

after that do:
sudo apt-get install openresolv

after that:
reboot the computer it will work .

Comment: why are you YELLING?

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu 23:04 installation the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink pints too `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`