# Wifi browser login problem

Tags: wireless, login, browser, hot-spot

We use a wifi network at my school in which you must login with your student account in the web brower. When I boot my laptop with Windows 7, it redirects me automatically to the login page.

But if I use Ubuntu 12.10 I can connect to the wifi network, but it doesn't show the login page. I tried with Chrome and Firefox, but both browsers won't show any page.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: This works for my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop without any special configuration. Have you tried refreshing the browser page? Can you add your Network Connection settings information by editing the question above?

Comment: I have the same problem. Just to confirm that we have the exact same problem: did you try to copy the IP of the login page you get in Windows 7, and use it on the Ubuntu firefox? I did that and it worked, so the only problem was the automatic redirection that was not working. Is that the case for you too?

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser such as chromium? I did this now and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. The hint to solving this was when I ran

```
sudo dhclient
```

and got the following message: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

The steps I took after that were from here: [Resolvconf -u gives the error "resolvconf: Error: /etc/resolv.conf must be a symlink"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54888/resolvconf-u-gives-the-error-resolvconf-error-etc-resolv-conf-must-be-a-sym)

That is, running these steps solved the problem:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: This worked for me on a Linux Mint installation from mid-2016. I'm assuming the resolve.conf file was supposed to be regenerated based each time the network connection changed.

Comment: worked like a charm xubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

Your problem may be [bug #1003842](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dnsmasq/+bug/1003842)

To fix this, with root privileges edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment out the line `dns=dnsmasq`: that is, put a `#` at the beginning of the line. Save the file.  Then restart network-manager.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then reconnect to the Wi-Fi network.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the fix did not work for me

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen at a coffeeshop - I tried the suggested "sudo dhclient" above but got the error "RTNETLINK answers: file exists".

I wondered if I had an actual IP address yet, so I did an "ip addr show" which told me I did indeed have a successful DHCP - out of curiosity, I figured I'd see if that LAN "router" address was open - so typed in the 192.168.x.1 (where x is the subnet of that coffeeshop) - and boom, the browser showed the login page just like windows did.

So anyway, if you're stuck, this might work for you too.  Thought I'd reply here because someone above helped me think about this with their dhclient comment.

Comment: Works most of the time, and I have had more luck with this in Firefox than other browsers. Some times I have found that it worked with 192.1.1, and 192.168.2.1, as well as 1.1.1.1 which is recommended in https://zapier.com/blog/open-wifi-login-page/

Comment: @Vass This was the only solution that helped. Trying the above, my friend's apartment had a login page 1.1.1.1, and I had to go through that page a couple times, and I hit "if nothing happens, click here" and it finally worked. Thank you.